# PyCharm + Matplotlib?

Tags: python, macos, matplotlib, pycharm

I can't seem to get pycharm to recognize my matplotlib module.. It runs fine from IDLE, yet it cant import from the IDE, anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Not enough information. How do you "import from the IDE"? Do you use `virtualenv`?

Comment: PyCharm is probably looking at the wrong python version

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it fixed I just moved my modules into opt/bin... and PyCharm seems to be working..

Comment: In the future you can just edit your PYTHONPATH environment variable to include said directory.