# Pycharm/Intellij not finding matplotlib

Tags: import, intellij-idea, pycharm

As in the sof question [Pycharm with matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15125583/pycharm-matplotlib)
  I am able to use numpy and matplotlib from python interpreter directly. In addition as suggested I have added the path to the matplotlib to the  PYTHONPATH.  But intellij still does not find those modules.  I am on os/x mavericks.

[image: import error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer by digging into Intellij documentation. The Module needs to be set to a Python interpreter library from Project settings| Modules | (Choose the module from middle pane ) | Dependencies tab on the right pane

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Same problem also occurred with me also, what I found that you have to install the package in PyCharm.
To do this:

---

### Step 1

> Open **Project Settings** and select '**Project Interpreter**' **Under 'Project: ....** ' and click on the '**+**' button.

[image]

---

### Step 2

> Now a new sub-window '**Available Packages**' will open, search the package you want to download like '**matplotlib**' and click on '**Install Package**'. Now the package will get installed.

[image]

---

*I hope this helped you and solved your problem :-)*

Comment: This is v much hit and miss: I find it more "miss" than hit.  After installing the package it usually still does not get picked up by the IJ interpreter. Sometimes _quitting_ Intellij helps: it _may_ "find" the new module upon restart and generate the skeletons.  There actually does not seem to be any foolproof way.

Comment: Actually it worked in my _case_ . I also tried `pip install matplotlib` . It successfully installed it but it was not detected in  _IJ interpreter_. I found the hint of the above solution from [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html).  I regret that it was not _useful_ in your case :-(

Comment: I did not actually say this approach does not _ever_ help. I don't always upvote an answer that did not work in my particular case but could help for other people: but you're just getting started so i'll make that effort here.